# How to query Quality of Service (QoS) Parameters of a ROS 2 Service from Command line

Tags: ros2, roscpp, rosservice, rosservices, qos

I know how to list ROS 2 services using the following command:

```
ros2 service list
```

I also know that we can display the QoS properties of a ROS 2 topic using the following command:

```
ros2 topic info -v <topic_name>
```

**Is there a similar way I could display the QoS profile of a ROS 2 service?**

Moreover, I am using ROS 2 C++ library function "create_service" to create a ROS 2 service node.

**Is there any C++ library function that would return the QoS property of a ROS 2 service, given the service name as an input?**

For example the "get_publishers_info_by_topic()" return the topic endpoint information about publishers on a given topic.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ninad

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Tomoya has implemented a ROS2 AI (openAI ROS2 based API) which can answer some questions about QoS and ros2 related to your application. You might be interested in it.

There is a nice tutorial video:

https://github.com/fujitatomoya/ros2ai

I still did not try, but seems interesting and maybe can help you in your needs.

Comment: Thank you Marcus!

I will try to use the API you suggested.